# Cant view React app on lan from another pc

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I just created a new react app using create-react-app.
when I tried access the app from another pc on the same lan, it seems to be loading but doesn't shows up.
**I am able to view the static files with no problem.**
Thanks for your help.

Update: Tried on other lan network and it's working! what can be the reason it doesn't work on the first lan?

Comment: Inspect network and console to provide more insights into your problem.

Comment: It seems that the browser is pending for the bundle.js nothing on console...

Answer (score 1):

See the [Create-React-App docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration):

> **HOST**:
>   By default, the development web server binds to `localhost`. You may use this variable to specify a different host.

Set the `HOST` environment variable ([in `.env`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) or in your shell) to `0.0.0.0` to bind to every address and you should be off to the races.

Comment: Tried it, didn't help, it keeps loading forever.

Comment: If you are sure the server is listening on all hosts, then there is a firewall or other network configuration preventing access from the other machine.

Comment: For example, you might have an active vpn connection on one of the pc's.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the port `3000` is open on your machine (or any other that you use).

In addition, you can try to serve application on `0.0.0.0` host instead of `localhost`.

Comment: I'm able to view the static files which means the server is accessible on port 3000

Answer (score 0):

To access your localhost react dev server on another computer on the same LAN you need to know the LAN IP of the host computer where the react dev server is running. On mac you can find the ip here: `System Preferences > Network > Advanced > TCP/IP`. It is either the IPv4 or IPv6 address.

Just replace localhost with the IP address when accessing the server with the other computer.

For example: `localhost:3000 > 192.168.1.179:3000`

Comment: I'm able to view the files on the other pc.